# Data visualization: Bubble charts, Venn diagrams, and tag clouds (oh my!)

Tags: javascript, r, charts, visualization, data-visualization

Suppose I have a large list of objects (thousands or tens of thousands), each of which is tagged with a handful of tags.
There are dozens or hundreds of possible tags and their usage follows a typical power law:
some tags are used extremely often but most are rare.
All but the most frequent couple dozen tags could typically be ignored, in fact.

Now the problem is how to visualize the relationship between these tags.
A tag cloud is a nice visualization of just their frequencies but it ignores which tags occur with which other tags.
Suppose tag :bar only occurs on objects also tagged :foo.
That should be visually apparent.
Similarly for three tags that tend to occur together.

You could make each tag a bubble and let them partially overlap with each other.
Technically that's a Venn diagram but treating it that way might be unwieldy.
For example, Google charts can create Venn diagrams, but only for 3 or fewer sets (tags):
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/venn_charts.html
The reason they limit it to 3 sets is that any more and it looks horrendous.
See "extentions to higher numbers of sets" on the Wikipedia page:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagrams

But that's only if every possible intersection is non-empty.
If no more than 3 tags ever co-occur (maybe after throwing out the rare tags) then a collection of Venn diagrams could work (with the sizes of the bubbles representing tag frequency).

Or perhaps a graph (as in vertices and edges) with visually thicker or thinner edges to represent frequency of co-occurrence.

Do you have any ideas, or pointers to tools or libraries?
Ideally I'd do this with javascript but I'm open to things like R and Mathematica or really anything else.
I'm happy to share some actual data (you'll laugh if I tell you what it represents) if anyone is curious.

**Addendum**: The application I originally had in mind was [TagTime](http://tagti.me) but it occurs to me that this also maps well to the problem of visualizing one's delicious bookmarks.

Comment: You seem to have left out the bit about *programming* from your question.

Comment: He asks what libraries he should use.  Unless, he is interested in checking out a book, this is probably a programming question.

Answer (score 5):

If i understand your question correctly, an ***image matrix*** should work nicely here. The implementation i have in mind would be an n x m matrix in which the tagged items are rows, and each tags type is a separate column. Every cell in the matrix would consist entirely of "1's" and "0's", i.e., a particular item either has a given tag or it doesn't.

In the matrix below (which i rotated 90 degrees so it would fit better in this window--so columns actually represent tagged items, and each row shows the presence or absence of a given tag across all items), i simulated the scenario in which there are *8 tags* and *200 tagged items*. , a **"0" is blue** and a **"1" is light yellow**.

All values in this matrix were randomly selected (each tagged item is eight draws from a box consisting of two tokens, one blue and one yellow (no tag and tag, respectively). So not surprisingly there's no visual evidence of a pattern here, but if there is one in your data, this technique, which is dead simple to implement, can help you find it.

I used **R** to generate and plot the simulated data, using only base graphics (no external packages or libraries):

```
# create the matrix
A = matrix(data=r1, nrow=1, ncol=8)

# populate it with random data
for (i in seq(0, 200, 1)){r1 = sample(0:1, 8, replace=TRUE); A = rbind(A, r1)}

# now plot it
image(z=A, ann=F, axes=F, col=topo.colors(12))
```

[image]

Comment: I do not think this kind of visualization would help finding patterns in the data given that there are "thousands of objects" and "hundreds of tags". The resulting image will probably be just a huge noisy picture.

Comment: A good [seriation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seriation/index.html) is very important for seeing patterns in this sort of display

Answer (score 2):

I would create something [like this](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/force.html) if you are targeting the web.  Edges connecting the nodes could be thicker or darker in color, or perhaps a stronger force connecting them so they are close in distance.  I would also add the tag name inside the circle.

Some libraries that would be very good for this include:

- [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/)  (Javascript)
- [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/)     (Adobe Flash)

Some other fun javascript libraries worth looking into are:

- [Processing for Javascript](http://processingjs.org/)
- [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Comment: Thanks Jay! I didn't know about protovis; that's excellent.  As for platform/language, web/javascript is ideal but if Mathematica or R or something has a great way to do this, I'd love to know about that as well.  As for the force-directed layout, what I don't like about that is that it's not capturing the subset relationships.  Maybe something like this -- http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/bubble.html -- but where the bubbles can be inside each other.

Comment: Thanks again, Jay. Protovis seems to be javascript, not flash, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old thread, I just came across it today.

You may also want to consider using a [Self-Organizing Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map).

Here is an example of a self-organizing map for world poverty.  It used 39 of what you call your "tags" to arrange what you call your "objects".

http://www.cis.hut.fi/research/som-research/povertymap.gif
[image: Self-Organizing Map for World Poverty]

Answer (score 1):

Note sure it would work as I did not test that, but here is how I would start:

You can create a matrix as doug suggests in his answer, but instead of having documents as rows and tags as columns, you take a square matrix where tags are rows and columns. Value of the cell T1;T2 will be the number of documents tagged with both T1 and T2 (note that by doing that you'll get a symetric matrix because [T1;T2] will have the same value as [T2;T1]).
Once you have done that, each row (or column) is a vector locating the tag in a space with T dimensions. Tags near each others in this space often occur together. To visualize co-occurrence you can then use a method to reduce your space dimensionality or any clustering method. For example you can use a kohonen self organizing map to project your T-dimensions space to a 2D space, you'll then get a 2D matrix where each cell represents an abstract vector in the tag space (meaning the vector won't necessary exists in your data set). This vector reflect a topological constraint of your source space, and can be seen as a "model" vector reflecting a significant co-occurence of some tags. Moreover, cells near each others on this map will represent vectors close to each other in the source space, thus allowing you to map the tag space on a 2D matrix.
Final visualization of the matrix can be done in many ways but I cannot give you advice on that without first seeing the results of the previous processing.